# Show that a polynomial f(x) over a field k is irreducible if and only if the polynomial f(x + 1) is irreducible.

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory

I am very much unsure what definitions and formulas are relevant for this question. I've toyed around with the lemma "An element a ∈ R is a root of a polynomial f ∈ R[x] if and only if (x − a) divides f" but come up with nothing useful.

Comment: **Hint**: proof by Contradition

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $f(x+1)=g(x)h(x)$ then $f(x)=g(x-1)h(x-1)$.

Comment: if i prove that f(x) is reducible <=> f(x+1) is reducible, does this adequately imply  f(x) is irreducible <=> f(x+1) is irreducible

Comment: Correct, Kieran. The contrapositives work that way. After you have proved that "$f(x)$ reducible $\implies$ $f(x+1)$ reducible", that is the contrapositive of "$f(x+1)$ irreducible $\implies f(x)$ irreducible", so you have proven that also. The same with the implications in the opposite direction.